# Can a Filter using JS and React filter an array twice without a temporary variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, frontend

```
Arr1 = [
        {
            “team”: “bears”,
            “coach”, “zeberthal”,
            “”quarterback” “mcman”
        },
        {
            “team”: “vikings”,
            “coach”, “jones”,
            “”quarterback” “cousins”
        }
    ]
]

Arr2 = [“vikings”, “bears”, “packers”, “cousins”, “mcman”]
```

Some of those values correspond to coach, some are quarterback and some are team. And as you can see sometimes a value is not present (for instance in Arr2 coach is not included). No duplicate values. But sometimes a team may not have a coach or quarterback so that object would have that field as “quarterback”: “” for instance.
I would like the filter to return only those values that will return a match (object) if all three fields match or whatever fields there happen to be match.
If I only filter for one field no problem:

```
 filteredForFirstValue => arr1.filter(function(result){
    return arr2.includes(result.team);
    }))
```

This filters out objects that don’t match the one field result.team but I also need filteredForFirstValue to then be filtered and to return only the objects that match quarterback so something like.

```
Filter2 = filteredForFirstValue.filter( function(result){
    return arr2.includes(result.quarterback);
    }))
console.log(filter2)
```

In React.js this is not working I am getting undefined on my filteredForFirstValue array.  Can anyone help me identify my issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can sum up your criteria

```
Filter2 = filteredForFirstValue.filter( function(result){
    var matches = 0;
    matches += arr2.includes(result.quarterback) ? 1 : 0;
    matches += arr2.includes(criteria2) ? 1 : 0;
    matches += arr2.includes(criteria3) ? 1 : 0;
    return matches >= X; // you can set the level of criteria that need to be matched
}))
console.log(filter2)
```

The main advantages of this solution over unmitigated's solution are

1. Efficiency: You don't have to create temporary arrays that are going to be refiltered
2. Flexibility: You can do a filter to match 2 of 3 criterias

Comment: for some reason trhis did not work for me.  What is the significance of the > x. If I want them to match all three is that just =3?? either way it did not work. Could also be i am using React.s

Comment: @questionsneedanswers I have changed the > x to >= x, x being the number of criteria that need to match

Comment: if a field was empty though or did not have a value and you set it for 3 (meaning sometimes if all 3 are there they should be used or what ever is there should be used) In that case would it not match  to empty string values? ie would it still match the other fields and return that object or would the empty field throw everything off?

Comment: @questionsneedanswers re: if a field was empty <- The answer I posted was based on your code. As you state, there may be times when there are edge cases that you'd want to deal with in the filter function. I can't and I won't hold your hand while you solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Define each filter as a function that accepts the array to filter as an argument. Then you can compose them together.

```js
const filter1 = arr => arr.filter(result => arr2.includes(result.team));
const filter2 = arr => arr.filter(result => arr2.includes(result.quarterback));
let res = filter2(filter1(arr1));
```